# i am doing sign Up page, when status=success i want to go back to the sign in page. but here not happening?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

```
   parameters:params
     progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"]);
     NSString *status=[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"];

     if([[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"]  isEqual: @"success"])
     {
```

here i want to goback to root ViewController

```
         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but nothing is happening here

```
     }
 }

 failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
```

Comment: is there any error you getting ? ..show some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a segue like you have previously, except drag a segue from the 'Sign up' view controller, to the 'Sign in' controller.

With the segue selected, set its Identifier in the Attributes inspector to say '**goToSignIn**'.
 Change your code to

```
if([[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"]  isEqual: @"success"])
     {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToSignIn" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dude  , You Saved My Life #Thithirru #Mandan

Answer (score 0):

Your completion block is not in main (UI) thread. Try this :

```
  __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
  parameters:params
  progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject){
  NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"]);
  NSString *status=[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"];

 if([[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"]  isEqual: @"success"]){
     // here i want to goback to root ViewController 
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
          });
  }
}
failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```